# Substitute all matches with values in Ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having a problem with getting a Ruby string substitution going. I'm writing a preprocessor for a limited language that I'm using, that doesn't natively support arrays, so I'm hacking in my own.

I have a line:

```
x[0] = x[1] & x[1] = x[2]
```

I want to replace each instance with a reformatted version:

```
x__0 = x__1 & x__1 = x__2
```

The line may include square brackets elsewhere.

I've got a regex that will match the array use:

```
array_usage = /(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/
```

but I can't figure out the Ruby construct to replace each instance one by one. I can't use `.gsub()` because that will match every instance on the line, and replace every array declaration with whatever the first one was. `.scan()` complains that the string is being modified if you try and use scan with a `.sub()!` inside a block.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actaully you can use [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000817), you just have to be careful to use it correctly:

```
s = 'x[0] = x[1] & x[1] = x[2]'
s.gsub!(/(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/, '\1__\2')
puts s
```

Result:

```
x__0 = x__1 & x__1 = x__2
```

Comment: Oh, magic, thank you.

This wasn't working for me because I wrapped the '\1__\2' in double-quotes "", not single ''. I will go and read up why Ruby treats each one differently. Thanks Mark!

Comment: @Lewisham: When you use double-quotes "\1" is interpreted as the escape code for ASCII character 1. When you use single quotes, the string is interpreted literally as a backslash followed by 1, which gsub recognises.

Comment: You can still use double quotes if you escape \1.  e.g. "\\1__\\2"